# Maven multi-module project compiles in eclipse but fails with maven command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, multi-module

A relatively huge maven project with 7 modules compiles using Eclipse but fails in the command line. The project is checked out in eclipse from SVN and a few steps are carried out to configure the JRE and other items. Then, I build the project using `right-click-project/Run as/Maven build ...` and then type the goals as `clean install`, select the skip tests checkbox, and click run. The build completes without any problem.

Now, I try to build the project using `mvn clean install` and some projects will succeed, one fails with errors, and the others are skipped. The output is as follows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rmic-maven-plugin:1.3:rmic (rmi-compile) on project adaptersansa: Error while executing the RMI compiler.:  Built-in RMIC compiler not available in JDK9. Add a dependency on org.glassfish.corba:rmic to the plugin. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :adaptersansa
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot and solve this problem to be able to compile the project using the maven command line?

---

## Update 1:

Thanks to `Lesiak` for the hint. Before running the command `mvn clean install`, I changed the environment variables `PATH` and `JAVAN_HOME` to point to JDK 1.8, and all worked fine. The default was pointing to JDK 18. I noticed that changing the JDK version inside the POM.xml file has no effect. Any idea how to solve this problem? I don't want to keep on changing the environment variables every time I use maven command lines.

Can I configure a Maven Java Project to use `JDK 1.8` regardless of the system environment variable settings?

Comment: Most likely you are using different JDK in Eclipse and in command line. Either apply the recommendation: "Built-in RMIC compiler not available in JDK9. Add a dependency on org.glassfish.corba:rmic to the plugin." OR change java version in your command line (precise instructions depend on OS)

Comment: In eclipse, I use JDK 1.8, however, in the command line `java -version` is 18.0.1.1. Since the env. variable is `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1`. I will try to change the JAVA_HOME in the same command prompt and try again.

Comment: I change the environment variables `PATH` and `JAVAN_HOME` to point to JDK 1.8, and all worked fine. I noticed that changing the JDK inside the POM.xml file has no effect. Any idea how to solve this problem? I don't want to keep on changing the environment variables everytime I use maven command lines.

Comment: I recommend using https://sdkman.io for managing different versions of Java in your environment. Or for this particular project you can create a .bat file to do the work for you, set the environment and run maven.

Comment: `Built-in RMIC compiler not available in JDK9. Add a dependency on org.glassfish.corba:rmic to the plugin.`